# Service Stack Rate Limiting

Tags: servicestack

I need to rate limit specific end points rather then all end points in the API application.

By default, the rate limit feature enforces rate limiting to all service end points. Is there way to enable it for selected end point by decorating the service with an attribute?

https://github.com/wwwlicious/servicestack-ratelimit-redis

Comment: You should raise an issue/feature request with the project so the author has a chance to see it.

Comment: Thanks. I will raise a request.